# How can I get result as array (one, two, three, one, two, three, one, two, three, one)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.

```
$a = array("one","two","three");
$b = array ( 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

Comment: i think you need to more describe your problem..?

Comment: Please explain better what you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the problem is. Please see: [ask] and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: possible dup of [Repeat array to a certain length?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3595662/689579)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the user contributed example in http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php

> ```
> $obj = new stdClass();
> $obj->Mon = "Monday";
> $obj->Tue = "Tuesday";
> $obj->Wed = "Wednesday";
> $obj->Thu = "Thursday";
> $obj->Fri = "Friday";
> $obj->Sat = "Saturday";
> $obj->Sun = "Sunday";
>
> $infinate = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($obj));
> foreach (new LimitIterator($infinate, 0, 14) as $value ) {
>     print($value . PHP_EOL);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a mapping function and use `array_map` as follows:

```
function numToName($num) {
    return array("zero","one","two","three","four","five",
                 "six","seven","eight","nine")[$num];
}

$b = array (0,8,2,3,7,5,6,0,4,1);   
$result = array_map("numToName", $b);
print_r($result);
```